# Just another problem on Integration:-

Tags: indefinite-integrals

[image]

What I tried was I took $$\tan^{-1}(x) =t, $$ but I got terms like $$\cos(\tan(t))$$  which I don't know what to do with.
So please guide me into solving this..

Comment: Problems like this make students hate calculus. Good god. I'm sure there's a relatively simple solution, but.. a problem like this is needlessly complicated for a calculus student.

Comment: Sir I can't write inverse functions in mathjax please help me @CameronWilliams

Comment: You were pretty close! $\rm\LaTeX$ requires curly brackets for exponents with more than one character, e.g. \tan^{-1}(x) to get $\tan^{-1}(x)$, but you could just do \sin^2(x) for $\sin^2(x)$.

Comment: In the picture, is $tan^{-1}x = arctan(x)$ or $cotx$?

Comment: @mrnovice. I think that you are right. It should be $\cot(x)$. Even in this case, it is a monster.

Comment: If $\tan^{-1}(x)$ means the arctangent function, then _Mathematica_ choked on this integral, so I very much doubt it has a closed form solution. But if $\tan^{-1}(x)$ means $\frac{1}{\tan(x)}=\cot(x)$, then _Mathematica_ did find an antiderivative for it, and even only in elementary functions, although it's not a pretty one.

Comment: But I am really sorry mate it is in fact arctanx @zipirovich@mrnovice

Comment: Holy bejesus. [This is the answer Wolfram Alpha gives in the case of $\tan(x)^{-1}$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%5E3(x)%2F((cos%5E4(x)%2B3cos%5E2(x)%2B1)*tan(x)%5E(-1)*(sec(x)%2Bcos(x)))) It hung on the case of it being $\arctan(x)$.

Comment: Anyone got wolfram alpha pro - my computation time was exceeded :(? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(sin%5E3x)%2F((cos%5E4x%2B3cos%5E2x%2B1)arctanx(secx%2Bcosx))+dx

Comment: Got the same on the app @mrnovice. Abandon hope ye who may enter here.

Comment: I have got Wolfram alpha pro from last 3 mins it is calculating .....@mrnovice

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: From my textbook for iitjee

Comment: I don't know what iitjee is, but why would it give you such a problem? Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Not at all ,these type of questions are reputed ,,don't worry about the accuracy of this question ,dude,just think of answering it.....@mrnovice

Comment: Don't be pushy. The reason for asking is that, as stated, this question seems impossible.

Comment: @satyatech Please upload a picture of the problem from your textbook directly. Probably you made a mistake while copying it here.

Comment: the site http://www.integral-calculator.com/ gives this result, I don't what the comma means ,$\ln\left(\operatorname{arctan2}\left(\cos^2\left(x\right)+1, \cos\left(x\right)\right)\right)$

Comment: @Vikram $\operatorname{arctan2}(x,y)$ is the polar angle coordinate of the point $(x,y)$. So when $x>0$ and $y>0$ we have $\operatorname{arctan2}(x,y)=\arctan(y/x).$ With other sign combos you may have to adjust by an integer multiple of $\pi$ (depending on the details of the definition).

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
$$t = \arctan \left ( \sec x + \cos x \right )
,\\dt = \frac{\sin ^{3}xdx}{\cos^{4}x+ 3\cos ^{2}x + 1 }\\
\int \frac{dt}{t} = \log_{e}  \arctan \left ( \sec x + \cos x \right ) + C$$

Comment: The factor in the denominator is $\arctan(x)( \sec (x)+ \cos (x))$ not $\arctan( \sec(x)+ \cos (x))$